# Email Attachments w/ base64 Encoding on Rhat

Tags: email, base64, redhat, sendmail, attachment

I am migrating from an old HP-UX box to a new Rhat box.  Our ERP emailer program saves the email (including MIME headers) as "Email_msg_*port*.html" and the attachment in the user's home dir.  No problem so far.

The emailer then issues the following command:

```
(cat Email_msg_8.html ; base64 /home/johnsmith/APMS9010.txt) | sendmail -t
```

The email itself is fine, but the attachment is always empty (though it *says* it is about 300 bytes).

My MIME header looks like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.1
From: myEmail@myCompany.com
To: myEmail@myCompany.com
Subject: APMS9010.1 - Download Top Vendor Purchase - LIVE.DATA
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="_boundarystring"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--_boundarystring
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Base: "http://myCompany.com/";
```

I have tried Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary (and 7bit)

Is my MIME stuff  wrong, the base64 command wrong, both, or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Does sendmail report any problems in the log file? Could you include internal mime headers of base64 encoded attachment?

Comment: There are no errors.  There is nothing in the attachment at all, so there is nothing to send to you.